# Parse Chinese DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-parsing

I'm trying to convert the following string to a DateTimeOffset

```
二 5月 16 14:41:40 +0800 2023
```

which translates to "Tue May 16 14:41:40 +0800 2023"

I have tried the following code:

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse(lastLogin, new CultureInfo("zh-CN"), DateTimeStyles.None)
```

But unfortunately without success.

I have also tried `ParseExact()` with the following formats: `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` and  `d MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. Also without success.

> System.FormatException: 'The string '二 5月 16 14:43:10 +0800 2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0'.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default zh-CN culture has the abbreviated day names as the following array:

```
"周日", "周一", "周二", "周三", "周四", "周五", "周六"
```

So you could create your own `DateTimeFormatInfo` object you can use to parse the string. You can use the zh-CN culture as the starting point:

```
using System.Globalization;

var zhcnCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN");
var writeableClone = (DateTimeFormatInfo)zhcnCulture.DateTimeFormat.Clone();
writeableClone.AbbreviatedDayNames = new string[] { "日", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六" };
// or use:
// writeableClone.AbbreviatedDayNames = writeableClone.ShortestDayNames;

var dateTxt = "二 5月 16 14:41:40 +0800 2023";
var format = "ddd M月 d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
var parsedDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateTxt, format, writeableClone);
```

You need to clone the starting point because the starting point is a readonly object that will give an error if you try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate says the first glyph is just "`two`", not Tuesday, with no hint of day-of-week. If I further start from English and translate to Chinese, Tuesday looks like this: `周二`.

If I then take the new glyph and use it as part of the input, [the parse succeeds.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eYTbqF)

Therefore I suggest your input string is somehow missing a character.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Joel. This string comes from the 'lastlog' command on a Chinese Ubuntu Linux server. So it could be that the DateTime is formatted wrongly in Linux. I'm not a Chinese speaker myself, so i'm not sure what the correct way of writing dates is in Chinese.

Comment: @Bart Since the day-of-week is redundant (implied by day/month/year), and you're parsing a log file where the date format should be consistent, I suggest always pre-trimming that first element before calling `Parse()` or `ParseExact()`